# Буква "ять"

Tags: алфавит, фонетика

Для чего в русском языке существовала буква "ять" и чем она отличалась от Е ("есть")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально в кириллице буква Е ("есть") обозначала звук Э. Ять, же, соответственно, соответствовала мягкому "йэ". Впоследствии, когда звук Э из русского языка практически ушел (в основном, все слова с этим звуком имеют иностранное происхождение), Ять стала чередоваться с Е в соответствии со сложными правилами.
Была упразднена из русского алфавита наркомом образования А.В. Луначарским в 1918 году.

Comment: Это не так. Ять обозначал звук, который приблизительно соответвовал дифтонгу ИЕ, а для "мягкого" Е употреблялся йотованный "есть".

Answer (score 5):

Буквой ять обозначался ныне исчезнувший "смягчающий" гласный звук переднего ряда, который условно считают дифтонгом ИЕ. Условность здесь в том, что в разные периоды и - главное - в разных диалектах он звучал по-разному. Это мог быть как собственно дифтонг ИЭ (ЙЭ, ИЙЭ, ИЫЭ), так и долгий гласный разного качества - ИИ, ЭЭ или средний между И и Э. В русских диалектах он сохранился до Петровской эпохи (судя по письменным источникам), после чего окончательно прешел в Е. В других славянских языках его судьба различна. В польском, например, он регулярно перешёл в Я, в украинском, за небольшими исключениями, - в И (ЙИ).

Считатется, что в наибольшей степени в современном русском языке призвук ятя сохранился в словах дед, хлеб и лес (именно в такой последовательности, от наибольшего к меньшему). 
Попробуйте нараспев произнести "дед" (должно получиться что-то типа диииэээт") - еще лучше детское "деда" ("деда, купи мороженое": "диииээээда") - получится что-то отдаленно напоминающее классический ять поздней эпохи его активного употребления (XIV-XVI век).

Comment: Хороший ответ.

Дополню, что на территории бывшей Югославии с **ѣ** -- особая история. Там три диалекта. 

В одном *ИЭ* перешло в *ИЙЕ*. Это т.н. иекавский диалект. Например, стар.-слав. *рѣка* -- рийека. Или иногда просто мягкое произношение вѣра -- вера (точно как в русском). Распространён в Хорватии и в какой-то степени в Сербии. 

Второй диалект -- экавский. ИЭ -> Э. вѣра -- вэра. Этому диалекту большее предпочтение отдают в Сербии. 

И ещё икавский диалект. ИЭ -> Э. вѣра -- вира (как в украинском). Этот диалект не очень распространён. Возможно (могу ошибаться), считается простоватым.

Comment: Мне интересно в этой истории следующее. Что все эти три варианта **ѣ** долгое время считались более-менее равноправными. И не было принято волевого политического решения "сверху", какой диалект считать литературным и единственно правильным.

В той же России, кажется, существовали северные говоры, где говорилось, к примеру "хлиб".

Comment: Ну, правда, после распада Югославии этих политический решений напринимали столько, что непонятно, как и что уже там политически правильно называть. Но это уже новейшая, недавняя, история, от 1990-х годов. А так, то бывшая Югославия интересна тем, что там в живом языке сохранилось немало славянской старины.